# Which buffers to flush?

Tags: c

I'm creating a client/server application in C where I re-use some existing code. Due to this, the server rather than the client is responsible for printing messages to the user. To achieve this, the server has opened stdout of the client by calling fopen() on '/proc//fd/1' and redirected its own stdout to this fd.

I wonder which buffers are involved when the server prints messages to understand what to flush?
The server obviously has to flush its own stdout, but will that be enough for the message to appear or will the output just end up at the buffer of the client's stdout?
Does the client also have to flush its stdout to make sure that the message is visible for the user?
Would a call to fsync() for both the server's and client's stdout make any difference?

The reason that I would like to fully understand which buffers are involved is that I've seen problems when the client's stdout is redirected to a file. I've read about the difference in line buffered and fully buffered output, so I suspect that the problem I have is related to the client's redirected stdout.

Comment: The server can only do the trick if the client runs on the same machine. It’s a moderately putrid trick.  The client should flush its standard output before sending a request to the server. If the server is using file stream I/O, then it needs to flush its redirected output before returning control to the client.

Comment: Yes they are obviously running on the same machine as I make use of the proc fs. I agree that it may not be a perfect solution, but due to the prerequisites of the project the server had to handle the output. I guess that the client has to flush in order to synchronize output with the server, but in this case the client will be completely silent so I guess it means that it not applicable? Based on what you say, I assume that output from the server will go straight to stdout or a file depending on what's defined in the client, without passing any buffer in the client(?).

Comment: The client code will never see any of the output from the server.  It will go direct to the file or device that the client is using as standard output.

Comment: So I guess that as long as the server manage to flush it's buffer it will be safe for the client to close the file (redirected stdout)? In case anything is missing in the file, it wasn't properly output/flushed by the server?

Comment: Probably.  Once the server has the file descriptor for the client’s standard output open, it shouldn’t matter if the client closes its output. And if only the server is writing to the client’s standard output, then any missing information is the server’s problem.  (I still think this is an appallingly awful design. I’m explaining what I believe will happen, but I still think that the design is wrong — utterly the wrong way to approach the problem.)

Comment: Well, I don't think that anyone would design a client/server solution like this from scratch, but when there are legacy code that can not be changed your options are limited. I'm just happy that I found one solution to the problem, though I still have problems in some rare cases. That's why I figured I had to understand all the details properly. Thanks!